# Models created incorrectly with Django shell or view but created correctly with admin

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to create cropped images from a image and save them in two separate models. I can upload and save the whole image fine. I have a function in the Crop module to assign a random string as the filename when created. This works fine when I create a Crop object with the admin interface. However, if I use the shell or just script in my view the crop is created but not saved to the right place.

Models.py:

```
def changeName(instance, filename):
    print ("SOMETHING")
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (name_generator(), ext)
    print filename
    return os.path.join('croppedImages/', filename)


def name_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

class Image(models.Model):
    wholeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'wholeImages/')
    level = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length =200)
    def save(self):
       if not self.id and not self.wholeImage:
           return
       super(Image,self).save()
       image = Im.open(self.wholeImage)
       image=image.resize((500,600),Im.ANTIALIAS)
       image.save(self.wholeImage.path)

class Crop(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    croppedImage = models.ImageField(upload_to=changeName)
    position_x = models.IntegerField()
    position_y = models.IntegerField()
```